# Nightwatch - Use chromedriver

Tags: selenium-chromedriver, nightwatch.js

So i saw a similar question on stack [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27601103/launch-tests-in-chrome-with-nightwatchjs-on-mac-os-connection-refused-is-sele) but it did not have an accepted answer nor did it provide me with the information i needed..

I am trying to use 'chromedriver' because 'selenium-webdriver' requires a FF version <= 28.

What i've done so far.

- nightwatch.js tests running fine in FF
- downloaded chromedriver (`npm install chromedriver -g`) and also `npm install chromedriver` into my nightwatch project directory
- went to `nightwatch/bin/nightwatch.json` and edited the following code

  ```
   "selenium" : {
  "start_process" : false,
  "server_path" : "",
  "log_path" : "",
  "host" : "127.0.0.1",
  "port" : 4444,
  "cli_args" : {
    "webdriver.chrome.driver" : "/usr/local/bin/chromedriver", <= added this - is this the binary?
    "webdriver.ie.driver" : "",
    "webdriver.firefox.profile" : ""
  }},
  ```

also tried to update the settings for selenium to have a start_process=true and server_path

```
 "selenium" : {
    "start_process" : true,
    "server_path" : "../selenium-server-standalone-2.39.0.jar",
    "log_path" : "",
    "host" : "127.0.0.1",
    "port" : 4444,
    "cli_args" : {
      "webdriver.chrome.driver" : "/usr/local/bin/chromedriver",
      "webdriver.ie.driver" : "",
      "webdriver.firefox.profile" : ""
    }
  },
```

Not sure if im pointing to the proper chromedriver file/folder

also edited the test settings

```
  "test_settings" : {
    "default" : {
      "launch_url" : "http://localhost",
      "selenium_host" : "127.0.0.1",
      "selenium_port" : 4444,
      "silent" : true,
      "disable_colors": false,
      "screenshots" : {
        "enabled" : false,
        "path" : ""
      },
      "desiredCapabilities" : {
        "browserName" : "chrome",   <= changed this from ff to chrome
        "javascriptEnabled" : true,
        "acceptSslCerts" : true
      }
    },
```

If i go to run the test (without a `-e <browser>`) e.g. `nightwatch -g <group>`, it launches fine in FF and runs..

If i try to specify the chrome browser (`-e chrome`) `nightwatch -g <group> -e chrome` i get the following error

```
ERROR There was an error while starting the test runner:


Error: Invalid testing environment specified: chrome
    at Object.CliRunner.parseTestSettings (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/nightwatch/lib/runner/cli/clirunner.js:354:15)
    at Object.CliRunner.init (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/nightwatch/lib/runner/cli/clirunner.js:31:8)
    at module.exports.runner.runner (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/nightwatch/lib/index.js:512:19)
    at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/nightwatch/bin/runner.js:9:16
    at module.exports.cli.cli (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/nightwatch/lib/index.js:504:7)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/nightwatch/bin/runner.js:8:14)
    at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
```

The questions i have are:

1. How do i point to the binary file (not sure which it is)
2. Are my settings in nightwatch.js correct? How is it running in FF if i changed the test_settings 'browserName = Chrome"?
3. Am i missing something here?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure to **create a new nightwatch.json file in the root** of your project.

The mistake i made was trying to use the nightwatch.json file that came with the package downlaoded from http://nightwatchjs.org/ that resided in `nightwatch-0.6.11/bin/nightwatch.json`

Answer (score 6):

First you said

> I am trying to use 'chromedriver' because 'selenium-webdriver'
> requires a FF version <= 28.

Its because you are using selenium-server-standalone-2.39.0.jar (Old jar) Please download new one from here [selenium-server-standalone-2.45.0.jar](http://www.seleniumhq.org/download/)
Second Download chrome driver from here [Chromedriver](http://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/index.html?path=2.15/) basis on your environment

Third update your nightwatch.json with below code

```
{
"src_folders": [
    "tests"
],
"selenium": {
    "start_process": false,
    "server_path": "bin/selenium-server-standalone-2.45.0.jar",
    "log_path": "",
    "host": "127.0.0.1",
    "port": 4444,
    "cli_args": {
        "webdriver.chrome.driver": "bin/chromedriver",
        "webdriver.ie.driver": ""
    }
},
"test_settings": {
    "default": {
        "launch_url": "http://127.0.0.1/",
        "selenium_port": 4444,
        "selenium_host": "localhost",
        "silent": true,
        "screenshots": {
            "enabled": false,
            "path": ""
        },
        "desiredCapabilities": {
            "browserName": "firefox",
            "javascriptEnabled": true,
            "acceptSslCerts": true
        }
    },
    "chrome": {
        "desiredCapabilities": {
            "browserName": "chrome",
            "javascriptEnabled": true,
            "acceptSslCerts": true
        }
    }
}
```

}

Fourth run your group with nightwatch -g  -e chrome

Hope It will solve your problem.

Comment: Thanks @juhi, didnt realzie that about selenium.jar file. But ended up being able to fix it by not using the default nightwatch.json file that was already in my project, created a new one on the root and all worked fine.

Comment: thanks for your input @juhi - it does help me, but the question was originally about using chromedriver.

Comment: No problem , but I think I have also mentioned how to give chrome driver path in nightwatch.json and also how to run group with chrome. Anyways no problem. Thanks for replying

Comment: Saved time.. Thanks mate

Answer (score 0):

```
"selenium": {
    "start_process":true,
    "server_path": "bin/selenium.jar",
    "log_path": "",
    "host": "127.0.0.1",
    "port": 4444,
    "cli_args": {
        "webdriver.chrome.driver": "",
        "webdriver.ie.driver": ""
    }
},
```

above code helps me to run selenium server by nightwatch

Comment: @ravi - thanks for sharing your solution. Have you tried running nigthwatch tests on a chrome node in a grid setting? If so, to do you configure nightwatch? I can't any documentation on this at all

Comment: Unfortunately I didn't find any Solution for Grid,But there is an alternate solution i.e By Using Docker I am trying to get this working I will update you if this is Successful

Comment: Hi Roobie
got the solution to run the night watch on selenium Grid