# Nightwatch chromedriver

Tags: selenium, nightwatch.js

I can't run nightwatch to run tests on chrome.

Here is my modified nightwatch.json that I downloaded from the nightwatch example:

```
{
  "src_folders" : ["./examples/tests"],
  "output_folder" : "./examples/reports",
  "custom_commands_path" : "./examples/custom-commands",
  "custom_assertions_path" : "",
  "globals_path" : "./examples/globals.json",
  "live_output" : false,

  "selenium" : {
    "start_process" : false,
    "server_path" : "/lib/sel-serv.jar",
    "log_path" : "",
    "host" : "127.0.0.1",
    "port" : 4444,
    "cli_args" : {
      "webdriver.chrome.driver" : "/lib/chromedriver/chromedriver.exe",
      "webdriver.ie.driver" : "",
      "webdriver.firefox.profile" : ""
    }
  },

  "test_settings" : {
    "default" : {
      "launch_url" : "http://localhost",
      "selenium_host" : "127.0.0.1",
      "selenium_port" : 4444,
      "silent" : true,
      "disable_colors": false,
      "screenshots" : {
        "enabled" : false,
        "path" : ""
      },
      "chrome":{
      "desiredCapabilities" : {
        "browserName" : "chrome",
        "javascriptEnabled" : true,
        "acceptSslCerts" : true
      }
      }
    },


      "desiredCapabilities": {
        "name" : "test-example",
        "browserName": "chrome"
      },
      "globals" : {
        "myGlobal" : "some_sauce_global"
      },
      "selenium" : {
        "start_process" : false
      }
  }
}
```

And I get this error message:

```
ERROR There was an error while starting the test runner:


Error: Invalid testing environment specified: chrome
    at Object.CliRunner.parseTestSettings (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/nightwatch/lib/runner/cli/clirunner.js:448:15)
    at Object.CliRunner.init (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/nightwatch/lib/runner/cli/clirunner.js:49:8)
    at module.exports.runner.runner (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/nightwatch/lib/index.js:546:17)
    at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/nightwatch/bin/runner.js:9:16
    at module.exports.cli.cli (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/nightwatch/lib/index.js:504:5)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/nightwatch/bin/runner.js:8:14)
    at Module._compile (module.js:409:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:416:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:343:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:300:12)
```

I also found a older post that says you have to create new file in root directory so give it a try and nothing happened

Comment: Can you try using relative directories instead of absolute ones?  My guess is that the path you're putting in your config file is not the path where your chrome driver is

Comment: this is the path to chrome driver. I put it there

Comment: Second guess is that night watch doesn't support absolute paths.  If you do a relative path, does it work?

Comment: nope. I used a relative path  lib/chromedriver/chromedriver.exe but nothing. i also tried ./lib/chromedriver/chromedriver.exe but now i get a path error.

Comment: Is the chrome driver actually in lib/chromedriver folder relative to your config file/wherever you're launching the tests from?

Comment: i used this guide <a href= "https://github.com/nightwatchjs/nightwatch/wiki/Windows-Quick-Start" >link</a> and my chrome driver is at 
C:\Dev\nightwatch\node_modules\nightwatch\lib\chromedriver\chromedriver.exe

Comment: Where is your config file?  If it's in C:/Dev, then your path needs to have nightwatch/node_modules/nightwatch prepended

Comment: config file you mean nightwatch json?

Comment: Yes that's the one

Comment: nightwatch json is under C:\Dev\nightwatch\node_modules\nightwatch

Comment: Have you tried this http://stackoverflow.com/a/30508959/3103678, try follow this. (y)

Comment: i think i tried this in past but i will give it a shot

Answer (score 3):

I think you need a dot before lib:

```
"webdriver.chrome.driver" : "./lib/chromedriver/chromedriver.exe",
```

also the selenium.jar:

```
"server_path" : "./lib/sel-serv.jar",
```

Answer (score 2):

Selenium server jar path and chrome driver (.exe) path is not set correctly. 
Use dot(".") to represent your working directory before setting path. Or remove the forward slash("/") before chrome driver and selenium server jar file path.

You have to run Selenium server standalone jar file manually because you have not set "start_process" to "true". Check Selenium Configuration here : http://nightwatchjs.org/gettingstarted/

You have set start_process property to false two times. Remove the last element from json file. ("selenium" : {
        "start_process" : false
      })

Also check browser version and driver are compatible or not, before you start execution.(Check the readme file from where you have downloaded the driver. Top line in readMe file will have browser compatibility versions).

Answer (score 1):

just check the configuration file and put the chrome object from out of the default object like,

```
     "test_settings" : {
"default" : {
  "launch_url" : "http://localhost",
  "selenium_host" : "127.0.0.1",
  "selenium_port" : 4444,
  "silent" : true,
  "disable_colors": false,
  "screenshots" : {
    "enabled" : false,
    "path" : ""
  }
  },
    "chrome":{
  "desiredCapabilities" : {
    "browserName" : "chrome",
    "javascriptEnabled" : true,
    "acceptSslCerts" : true
  }
},

    like this....have a blast
```

Answer (score 0):

If your chromedriver and selenium standalone jar are in the files you are pointing to, then I think you are only missing the config to start the server before tests run. See the line...

```
"start_process" : false,
```

You need to set that to true like so...

```
"start_process" : true,
```

Unless you plan to start the server manually before you run the tests. Once that is done, consider the paths as was mentioned above. Depending if running on Windows, Mac or Linux; this can require the `.` in front of the `/`.

Answer (score 0):

Nightwatch configuration for chrome driver will be-

```
{
  "src_folders" : ["tests"],
  "output_folder" : "reports",
  "page_objects_path": "./pages",
  "selenium" : {
    "start_process" : true,
    "server_path" : "./bin/selenium-server-standalone-3.4.0.jar",
    "log_path" : "",
    "port" : 4444,
    "cli_args" : {
      "webdriver.chrome.driver" : "./bin/chromedriver"
    }
  },
  "test_settings" : {
    "default" : {
      "launch_url" : "http://localhost",
      "selenium_port"  : 4444,
      "selenium_host"  : "localhost",
      "desiredCapabilities": {
        "browserName": "chrome",
        "javascriptEnabled": true,
        "acceptSslCerts": true
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Here, chrome has been made default broswer.

Answer (score 0):

```
  "selenium": {
    "start_process": true,
    "server_path": "./lib/drivers/selenium-server-standalone-3.141.59.jar",
    "log_path": "",
    "host": "127.0.0.1",
    "port": 4444,
    "cli_args": {
      "webdriver.chrome.driver": "./lib/drivers/chromedriver.exe",
      "webdriver.gecko.driver": "",
      "webdriver.edge.driver": ""
    }
  },
```

You supposed to write in your nightwatch.json like that.
Additionally make sure that your web-driver is in the same version like your chrome browser (if it will not be in the same version it will not run, and not give you any error message)